# convert char pointer with known length to vector of char without allocate new memory

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I try to create a a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) from a given char pointer witout allocating new memory. So that they work on the same memory.

I tried this:

```
int main()
{
char* test1 = "test value";   

std::vector<char> testVector(test1, test1 + strlen(test1));
testVector[4] = 0;

std::cout << test1 << std::endl;
std::cout << &(testVector[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

But this doesn't work the output is:

> test value
>   test

But if they work on th same memory it must be:

> test
>   test

Is there a way for this?

Comment: `vector`s copy whatever you feed them, the entire point of a `vector` is to manage the lifetime of its contents, if you don't need that then don't use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if they work on the same memory

The answer is, they don't work on same memory. When you construct a vector, it allocates space for itself and copies the contents.

So, the behaviour that you are getting is correct and expected.

To achieve what you want, write a custom memory allocator for vector.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this can't be done. Each new `vector` will allocate memory for itself and copy the string in. There is no way around this.

If you are determined to have a `vector<char>` and a `const char *` that point to the same location, you must create the `vector<char>` first. But that's a weird solution to a weird problem.

Anyway, this is C++, so you shouldn't be using `vector<char>` or `char *` very often anyway. Just use `std:: string`.

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std:: string test_string = "test value";
    test_string.at(4) = '-';
    std::cout << test_string << std::endl;
}
```

And it's easy to ask a `string` for its underlying (`const`) C array, for example if you have old C code you must interface with. [`const char * char_pointner = test_string.c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a vector, it always allocate a new array.

If you give an array as parameter like you did, it will allocate a new one of the same size and copy content from the source.

There is no way to do this with a `std::vector`. You'll have to use natives arrays if you want to work with different pointers on the same array:

```
char  test1[] = "test value";
char* testPtr = test1;

testPtr[4] = 0;

std::cout << test1 << std::endl; // Print "test".
std::cout << testVector << std::endl; // Print "test" as well.
```

By the way, as you saw, you should declare your first array with `char []` syntax instead of `char *`, else your variable will be readonly and you won't be able to edit it.

### Note:

Even if it works, this is more a C tan a C++ practice. Consider to learn about [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) object for character manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your char pointer test1 is keeping its memory in stack, but vector always create a location in heap using its default allocator.

If you need to achieve this you have to write a custom allocator for vector and use similar memory allocation strategy for your local variable.